# How can i print all the coefficient in one table?

Tags: sas

I have a script in sas that output a lot's of tables of regression:

```
FILENAME RegProj URL "http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~liadshek/Long.txt" ;
DATA book;
   length country $20;
   INFILE RegProj firstobs=2 dlm=" " LRECL=131072 dsd truncover;
   INPUT Country$ Year GDP_per_capita Infant_Mortality_Rate;
   log_IMR = log(infant_mortality_rate);
   log_gdp = log(GDP_per_capita);
RUN;

PROC reg data=book;
   by year;
   MODEL log_IMR = log_gdp;
   output out = reg1;
run;
```

How can i print all the coefficient in one table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the outest option - try the following:

```
PROC reg data=book outest = reg_estimates;
by year;
MODEL log_IMR = log_gdp;
output out = reg1;
run;
```

This gives you all the regression coefficients in one table.